# get the value from an entry in a properties file via CSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to access the value of an entry I have made in a properties file

e.g. 
the file is called datasource.properties
the entry is called DB_FILEPATH
and the value is mydatadb.nsf

In SSJS I would collect the value via datasource.getString('KEY') so datasource.getString('DB_FILEPATH')

To run SSJS from CSJS I normally use something like:

```
var isMobile = '#{javascript:return deviceBean.isMobile()}';
```

but if I try somthing like:

`var db = "#{javascript:return datasource.getString('DB_FILEPATH')}"`;

I get the error message:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=19: [ReferenceError] 'datasource' not found

How should I access the properties file via CSJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your "datasource" as resource:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:bundle src="/datasource.properties" var="datasource"></xp:bundle>
</xp:this.resources>
```

and access entries with

```
var db = "#{javascript: datasource['DB_FILEPATH']}";
```

Comment: found out the bundle was indeed not available

Comment: EL: #{datasource.DB_FILEPATH}